# Formalising sentence into predicate logic check

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Have been working on some predicate logic examples and was hoping someone could have a check-over to make sure it's correct. Here are the questions and my attempts;

1. Only pink pigs like sleeping and drinking.

   ```
    ∃ X • (pink(X) ∧ pigs( X ) ⇒ sleeping( X ) ∧ drinking( X ))
   ```
2. The child of a pink and a purple pig is red.

   ```
    ∀x∀y[(pinkPig(x) ∧ purplePig(y)) ⇒ ∀z(childOf(z,x,y) ⇒ red(z))]
   ```

Would really appreciate any help to check to see if these are correct.

Thanks.

**Update**

Have made amendments to the 1st answer as per below;

```
      ∀ X • (sleeping(X) ∧ drinking( X ) ⇒ pink( X ) ∧ pigs( X ))
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could take the time to review what I've managed so far!

Thanks.

Comment: (1) is very wrong. Your formula says "there is something that _either_ is not a pink pig _or_ likes sleeping and drinking". (Using a $\to$ as the connective immediately below an $\exists$ almost never makes good sense). You want, "everything that likes sleeping and drinking is a pink pig".

Comment: sorry I'm brand new to this - so should it be the following ... ∀ X • (sleeping(X) ∧ drinking( X ) ⇒ pink( X ) ∧ pigs( X )) ?? @HenningMakholm

Comment: x @Sam: Yes, that looks better.

Comment: There's a minor ambiguity here. Does "only pink pigs" mean "only creatures that are both pink and pigs" or "of all pigs, only the pink ones". In other words, can grey elephants like sleeping and drinking?